# MySQL SUM Transcat SQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to get a Total of a SUMs of different fields in different tables, can you archive this in one query?
Below is what I tried but it gives me totally wrong results:

```
SELECT (
         SUM(t1.Amount_Total) + 
         SUM(t2.Amount_Total) + 
         SUM(t3.Amount_Total) + 
         SUM(t4.Amount_Total) + 
         SUM(t5.Amount_Total) + 
         SUM(t6.Amount_Total) + 
         SUM(t7.Amount_Total) + 
         SUM(t8.Amount_Total)) AS Overall_Amount_Total FROM 
Table1 t1,
Table2 t2,
Table3 t3,
Table4 t4,
Table5 t5,
Table6 t6,
Table7 t7,
Table8 t8
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a temporary table `CREATE TEMP TABLE AS SELECT...`

Comment: @F.Hauri, any example how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this syntax:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT SUM(Amount_Total) FROM Table1)+
  (SELECT SUM(Amount_Total) FROM Table2)+
  .... AS overall_amount_total
```